# Remove overflow hover on client logos

Tags: css, wordpress

I am attempting to remove the hover effect padding on a Wordpress plugin called "Smart logo showcase". Here is the test page I have been working on:

http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/afroteqadvisory/test-clients/

So basically just the logo needs to be hoverable with no extra padding around it.

I have tried various code snippets and the class is called .smls-grid-image-wrap for the entire logo block.

I have tried to use padding: 0; but with no luck. Please assist

Comment: Your `.smls-grid-image-wrap ` element has `min-height` set in several places, try to remove this and only after that remove `padding` from this element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `min-height` and `min-width` are applied.

You can try tu use these properties for disable that

```
min-height: inherit;
max-height: inherit;
padding: 0;
```

Then, if you want to add spaces between elements you can add `margin`

Or, you can "hack" this with transparent background instead of color     #d5fcfd

You can try

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer Cyril :)

Comment: If this answer solve your problem you can click on the "Check" on the left of my post to validate this answer

Comment: @Bradley, you should accept this answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.smls-hover-type-2 .smls-grid-image-wrap:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Most welcome. If answer is helpful for you then accept it